# Where is my git alias stored?

Tags: git, alias

I have an alias that I cannot find. Typing `git help subaddvim` gives me:

```
`git subaddvim' is aliased to `log HEAD'
```

I think I defined it like this:

```
git config --local alias.subaddvim 'log HEAD'
```

I looked in `$repo_path/.gitconfig`, `~/.gitconfig`, `/etc/gitconfig`, but none of them have a subaddvim entry.

Where else can I look?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference between using the undocumented (or is it obsolete) `--local` flag and no flag. Git never looks for a gitconfig in your repository root (`$repo_path/.gitconfig`). Repo-local config changes are in `.git/config`.

`git help config` explains the valid options:

--global
       For writing options: write to global ~/.gitconfig file rather than the
       repository .git/config.

```
   For reading options: read only from global ~/.gitconfig rather than from
   all available files.
```

--system
       For writing options: write to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather
       than the repository .git/config.

```
   For reading options: read only from system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
   rather than from all available files.
```

(Using git version 1.7.9)

You could try searching with this (from your repo root and assuming git is installed in /bin):

```
grep subaddvim .git/config ~/.gitconfig /etc/gitconfig
```

Comment: I opened the .gitconfig file in installed folder. But I couldn't see any alias which I already have. Simply, I cannot found the text file where the alias have written.

Comment: @HareenLaks Did you try the grep command at the end of the answer? Replace `subaddvim` with the alias you're looking for.

Answer (score 24):

Scott Chacon's [excellent book "Pro Git"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) covers where things are stored, and what options to pass to `git config` to read/write to that location:

> Git comes with a tool called git config that lets you get and set
>   configuration variables that control all aspects of how Git looks and
>   operates. These variables can be stored in three different places:
>
> - /etc/gitconfig file: Contains values for every user on the system and
>     all their repositories. If you pass the option **--system** to git config,
>     it reads and writes from this file specifically.
> - ~/.gitconfig file:
>     Specific to your user. You can make Git read and write to this file
>     specifically by passing the **--global** option.
> - config file in the git
>     directory (that is, .git/config) of whatever repository you’re
>     currently using: Specific to that single repository. Each level
>     overrides values in the previous level, so values in .git/config trump
>     those in /etc/gitconfig.

You can have git tell you what's defined where using the `--list` option:

```
# shows all settings
git config --list

# shows system settings
git config --list --system

# shows user settings
git config --list --global

# shows project settings
git config --list --local
```