# Is there something shorter for git config --list --local?

Tags: git, shell

Is there something shorter for `git config --list --local`
(git properties for local git repository) ?

Like `git ll` ?

Comment: No, but Git supports aliases that you define yourself. If you want `git ll` to mean `config --list --local`, define that as an alias, and then `git ll` will do that. See [Where is my git alias stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11747691/1256452) for example.

Comment: to add to torek's comment : `git config --global alias.ll "config --list --local"` (that would be as a global alias, drop `--global` if you want to define this alias for this local repo only)

Comment: that would be perfect answer